# Does the message part of the PHP mail() function need to be escaped?

Tags: php, security

I'm creating a feedback webpage. I want to just take a textarea of user input and ship it off to myself with the [`mail`](http://php.net/mail) function. Is it safe to do the following:

```
mail("me@blah.com", "Feedback!", $_POST['feedback'], "From: myself@blah.com");
/*    (to)           (subject)    (message)           (headers) */
```

Or do I need to somehow escape or sanitize `$_POST['feedback']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should sanitize it as a **general practice**, but there's not too much that can go wrong here, just make sure that in the headers you specify:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Then no user can send anything "malicious" for you to click on, perform some sort of tracking, etc. (EDIT: without you knowing what it is, of course; what I mean is, no misleading links, 1x1 transparent GIFs or the like)

Answer (score 1):

As stilstanding said - you still need to sanitize any user-supplied data.

I would also recommend using a script like PHPMailer to create and send email messages. This will take care of formatting the message securely and makes tasks like sending multipart html/text messages much easier:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/

Comment: I like your recommendation to use PHPMailer as a general rule, but for a really basic contact form it might be more overhead than is necessary.  Then again, it could be a great place to swing it in, get used to it and start using it in more places.  Seventeen thousand sides to every coin =)

Comment: I have used PHPMailer in other parts of the site for HTML mailings, but in this case as Dereleased said I figured I'd just use the mail function for this very small, simple page.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on who is receiving the message. E.g. if it's GMail, they have their fair arsenal of escaping anything there, and anyone will have a really hard time injecting anything into it. But say, if someone is going to look at the message from some webmail, and if that webmail is of an outdated version, someone with a bad intention might be able to do something bad.

If you are not going to check for `<script>` tags and such, you have to do no escaping. But you'd better encode your email in quoted-printable, for deliverability rather than security, a task which is best done by a good mail class/function like [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html). And you can use it stand-alone (i.e. without the other library components).

Answer (score 0):

"Sanitize" is a kind of vague term. There are different types of encoding for different purposes.

If you're sending plain-text messages, I don't think you need to worry about encoding them. PHP's mail function should take care of any encoding needed.

If you're sending HTML messages, then you do need to HTML-encode all HTML attributes and content, regardless of whether the values come from the user or not.